# === not working properly

Tags: inequalities, operators

I've been trying to check the identity using wolfram Mathematica and I've found the following

```
ppo = Plus[Times[Rational[1,6],Power[a,2],Plus[1,Subscript[i,3]],Plus[2,Subscript[i,3]],Plus[6,Times[-3,s],Times[2,Subscript[i,3]]]],Times[Rational[1,2],Plus[1,Subscript[i,3]],Plus[2,Subscript[i,3]],Plus[6,Times[-5,s],Power[s,2],Times[Plus[5,Times[-2,s]],Subscript[i,3]],Power[Subscript[i,3],2]],Power[Superscript[a,0],2]]]

ppn = Plus[Times[Rational[-1,6],Power[a,2],Plus[-6,Times[3,s],Times[-2,Subscript[i,3]]],Plus[2,Times[3,Subscript[i,3]],Power[Subscript[i,3],2]]],Times[Rational[1,2],Plus[2,Times[3,Subscript[i,3]],Power[Subscript[i,3],2]],Plus[6,Times[-5,s],Power[s,2],Times[Plus[5,Times[-2,s]],Subscript[i,3]],Power[Subscript[i,3],2]],Power[Superscript[a,0],2]]]
```

And when I try to compare these two expressions with

```
ppo === ppn
```

It returns `False`

But this is actually an identity
[image]

So what's the problem here? Am I getting something wrong?

Comment: `Simplify[ppn == ppo]` gives `True`. Don't use `===`. Your ideas about its semantics are wrong.

Comment: `Expand[ppo] === Expand[ppn]` works as well, but the point is that `ppo` and `ppn` are not *structurally equivalent* expressions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SameQ` (`===`) is working as expected.

See the evaluation trace result:

```
FullSimplify[ppo === ppn] // Trace
```

[image]

Now see this result:

```
FullSimplify[ppo] === FullSimplify[ppn]

(* True *)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

`ppo` and `ppn` may be mathematically identical, but they are not the same structurally. Thus, `===` returns `False`. Use `==`, and coax it to do the work with `Simplify`.

```
Simplify[ppo == ppn]
(* True *)
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying "same structurally"?

Comment: Look at `x (y + 1) // TreeForm` and `x y + x // TreeForm`. Do you see the difference? `===` effectively compares `FullForm`, of the expressions, and `TreeForm` is just a visualization of that.

Comment: Wow, thank you a lot.